# I'm getting an error message while trying to run serve -s build

Tags: node.js, npm

I was working on my first react project and now trying to deploy it in Netlify so I ran `npm install -g serve` then `serve -s build` after running `npm run build`
but I'm getting the following error message while I ran `serve -s build`
what is the problem here

```
serve : File C:\Users\Akhlak Hossain Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\serve.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ serve -s build
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your PowerShell is preventing you from executing "possibly" harmful scripts, therefore, you have to change your execution policy, simply type this:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

May be you will need to start your terminal as an administrator in order to do this

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while trying to serve my react app using terminal of visual code. I just switched from the terminal of visual code to command prompt and it worked. But you have to install serve package in that folder(where your app currently resides) running command "npm install -g serve" first then run "serve -s build".